# AdonisJS dynamics routing in html <a> not working

Tags: adonis.js

I'm currently working with AdonisJS but I've a problem with the dynamic routing. I made some research but I didn't find anything that solve my problem.
My code :

**BlogController.ts**

```js
...
async show ({params, view}: HttpContextContract) {
  const post = await Post.findOrFail(params.id)
  return view.render('blog/show', {
    post
  })
}
```

**routes.ts**

```
...
Route.get('/article/:id', 'BlogController.show').as('posts.show')
```

**index.edge**

```
...
@each(post in posts)
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="{{ route('posts.show', {id: post.id}) }}"> // here's the error
        {{ post.title }}  
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
@endeach
...
```

**ERROR** : *E_CONNOT_MAKE_ROUTE_URL: "id" param is required to make URL for "/article/:id" route*

I tried to write the link in clear text like `<a href="article/0">` or `<a href="article/{{post.id}}">` and it works but not with the routing.